# Owl Carousel static background

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I want only the text to change and the background to remain static.
Here is my code:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  nav: true,
  navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
  items: 1,
  responsiveClass: true,
  autoHeight: true,
  lazyLoad: true,
  lazyLoadEager: 2
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="owl-carousel longread_slider_text owl-lazy" style="background: url('https://picsum.photos/1000/300'); background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;">
  <div class="slide-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="image" style="opacity: 0;">
    <div class="text">
      <div>
        <span class="title">Title One</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="image" style="opacity: 0;">
    <div class="text">
      <div>
        <span class="title">Title Two</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I set the background for the carousel and make the images invisible. But then the background covers the navigation points.
Any ideas on how to implement this?

[image]

upd: Owl Carousel version 2.3.4

Comment: Why are you even adding the `img` tags to each slide markup if you are just hiding them?

Comment: the size of the slider and its area depends on the size of the img inside it. Without them, the slider is not displayed. I know that this is not correct, but I could not think of another solution

Comment: You could try setting sizes using CSS. That would be the most obvious solution.

Comment: Yes, but it's a problem: How to make the image uniform and static for all slides. So that only the text changes

Comment: What version of Owl Carousel are you using?

Comment: Owl Carousel version 2.3.4

Comment: Edit the snippet I added to add your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

What if you devide carousel from dots?
There is param `dotsContainer`
Create after carousel empty div with id `owldots`.
Then set param in your code:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  nav: true,
  navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
  items: 1,
  responsiveClass: true,
  autoHeight: true,
  lazyLoad: true,
  lazyLoadEager: 2,
  dotsContainer: '#owldots' //Here
});
```

It's help you to set background only for carousel and create other styles for dots. In the such way you can create other div for navs (arrows) and set it by param `navContainer`